# MouseDown event not bubbling up to Button Click event when displaying a MessageBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, routed-events

Version 1 XAML code:

```
<Button Padding="10" Background="Green" Width="500">
    <StackPanel MouseDown="StackPanel_MouseDown" Background="Gray" Width="500" Height="300">
        <Ellipse MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red"></Ellipse>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Version 1 Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Ellipse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is the Ellipse");
        // Shows this MessageBox.
    }

    private void StackPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is the StackPanel");
        // Also shows this MessageBox.
    }
}
```

When I have 2 `MouseDown` events, one for the `Ellipse` and one for the `StackPanel`, whether I use `MessageBox` or not, it still bubbles up fine after showing the first `MessageBox`.

However, it stops working if I have the `Click` event on the `Button`.

Version 2 XAML Code:

```
<Button Padding="10" Background="Green" Width="500" Click="Button_Click">
    <StackPanel Background="Gray" Width="500" Height="300">
        <Ellipse MouseDown="Ellipse_MouseDown" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Red"></Ellipse>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Version 2 Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Ellipse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is the Ellipse");
        // Shows this
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is the Button");
        // Doesn't get to this point.
    }
}
```

**Now, the weird thing is, if I remove the `MessageBox` code in the `Ellipse` handler from Versio n2, and put anything else, it will then bubble up to the `Button`'s handler and show the "This is the Button" message.**

What is this weird behavior? Why does Version 1 bubble up and show **BOTH** `MessageBox`es but Version2 only shows one `MessageBox` and doesn't bubble up unless I remove the `MessageBox` code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I have 2 MouseDown events, one for the Ellipse and one for the Stackpanel, whether I use MessageBox or not, it still bubbles up fine after showing the first MessageBox.

This is because you do not set the [`Handled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.routedeventargs.handled?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.Handled);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) property to `true` to stop bubbling further.

```
private void Ellipse_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("This is the Ellipse");
   e.Handled = true;
   // Shows this
}
```

> Why does Version 1 bubble up and show BOTH MessageBoxes but Version 2 only shows one MessageBox and doesn't bubble up unless I remove the MessageBox code?

[This related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4556733/6181599) suggests that showing the message box effectively moves the focus away from the WPF window, which cancels the event routing regardless of setting the `Handled` property.

> The focus change to the message box cancels the mouse down event so it doesn't matter whether it is handled or not.

However, I do not agree with this. From my observations and tests, this issue is only related to modal windows (blocking your UI from interaction). You can create a WPF `Window` and call `ShowDialog`, which leads to the same behavior, while showing a window using `Show` or executing any external application will not stop event routing, even though the focus is moved away from the WPF application. Furthermore, as you show with your code, there can be any number of controls handling `MouseDown` by showing a modal window as children of a `Button` which will still work, only to break for the `Click` event handler of the `Button`.

In fact, investigating events with [Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf), shows that event handling is the same (left modal windows), the event **is not cancelled**. The event is always handled by the `Button`, which is expected as it is implemented this way, but the `Click` event handler is never called if there was any modal window shown before, although the event is not `Handled` (`false`).

[image: Snoop - Events, left modal windows, right non-modal.]

Consequently, I would assume that the event handling for `Click` is somehow broken in scenarios with modal windows. I have not found anything in the documentation about this issue or what is expected, only a [similar issue in the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6aeb09ed-8245-4688-8a62-64419136b224/wpf-tabcontrol-previewmouseleftbuttondown-event-issue-with-messagebox?forum=wpf).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So, I am assuming that this is a bug internally?

Comment: @Sound I cannot find any documentation on this behavior. Personally, I would consider this a bug, as this may break anything event related like animations up the visual tree or similar, just by using a modal window, which I would not expect. Nevertheless, this could be another oddity in WPF that is undocumented or even expected, I cannot tell.